# How to extract data from LONG datatype field using only SQL (without using PL/SQL block)?

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar2, oracle8i

How to extract data from `LONG` datatype field using only SQL (without using PL/SQL)?
Getting error while concatenating with other columns-

> ORA00932: inconsistent datatypes

DB: Oracle 8i enterprise edition

Comment: Since this is an Oracle problem, what is preventing you from using PLSQL here, as [this article describes](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/long_value.php) ?

Comment: Business constraints.. I am not allowed to use PL/SQL

Comment: So are you asking for a general SQL value to extract the value of the `LONG` ?  Can you update your question with what is the exact use case here?  Is this a one time need, or do you foresee having to do this often?

Comment: Yes.. Any predefined function or any sql statement that can extract the Value...

Comment: I don't think this is possible with your ancient and unsupported Oracle version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick using XML:

```
SELECT
    long_column long_column_as_clob
FROM
  XMLTABLE(
    'ROWSET/ROW'
    PASSING
      XMLTYPE(
        DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML(
          Q'{SELECT long_column FROM your_table}'
        )
      )
    COLUMNS
      long_column CLOB PATH 'LONG_COLUMN'
  );
```

Comment: This will not work in Oracle 8i enterprise edition. `XMLTABLE` was introduced in Oracle 10 R2.

Comment: Oops, sorry, haven't noticed the version. XML table is not needed you can extract the data from the XML using other functions too but if `DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML` is not available in Oracle 8i then you have a problem.